# Python GUI and animation

Tags: python, user-interface, animation, matplotlib, tkinter

I am creating a GUI to plot live graphs from temperature sensors using tkinter, and animation function from matplotlib. I am getting beautiful live graphs. But the problem I am facing is that the live graphs start as soon as I run the application. I have created a button to call a command in **class StartPage** but it doesn't work. I want my application to start collecting data and plotting graphs when I click **Start Monitoring** in class StartPage.

```
def animate(i):

    ipcon = IPConnection()  # Create IP connection
    ptc1 = BrickletPTC(UID1, ipcon)  # S3
    ptc2 = BrickletPTC(UID2, ipcon)  # S7
    ptc3 = BrickletPTC(UID3, ipcon)  # S7
    ptc4 = BrickletPTC(UID4, ipcon)  # S7

    ipcon.connect(HOST, PORT)  # Connect to brickd
    temperature1 = ptc1.get_temperature() - 20
    temperature2 = ptc2.get_temperature() + 6
    temperature3 = ptc3.get_temperature() + 3
    temperature4 = ptc4.get_temperature() + 29

    l = [temperature1, temperature2]
    avgTemp = np.mean(l)
    avgTempM = str(avgTemp / 100)

    dataArrayavg = avgTempM.split(',')
    tempavg = float(dataArrayavg[0])
    tempCavg.append(tempavg)
    avg.set_xlabel('Time [s]', fontsize=10)
    avg.set_ylabel('Temperature [°C]', fontsize=10)
    y_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
    avg.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_formatter)
    titleavg = "Average Room Temperature: " + str(temperature1 / 100) + " °C"
    avg.set_title(titleavg, fontsize=12)
    avg.plot(tempCavg, "#483D8B")

    f1.savefig('RoomTemperature.png')
    f2.savefig('ObjectTemperature.png')


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # Adding a logo to the startpage
        logo = Image.open("Gemeinschaftslogo(5).jpg")
        Image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)

        # defining the image label
        imageLabel = Label(self, image=Image1)
        imageLabel.image = Image1
        imageLabel.pack(pady=30, padx=30)

        # defining labels
        label = ttk.Label(self,
                          text="Zustandsüberwachung (Condition Monitoring) von industriellen Computertomographie-Systemen",
                          font=LARGE_FONT, )
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        # creating button
        # if agree then move to temperature graph
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Start Monitoring",
                             command=lambda: animate())  # with lambda we are moving from start page to page 1

        button1.pack(pady=30, padx=30)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Enter",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(
                                 RoomTempGraph))  # with lambda we are moving from start page to page 1


ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(f1, animate, interval=1000)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: your indentation appears broken.  It's not clear how much code belongs inside `def animate(i):`

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for replying might have been mistake during copying the text. The indentation inside animate(i) is good.

Comment: I suppose this is the line that triggers the animation: `ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(f1,animate, interval = 1000)`. That should be moved in the button commands. And in the button1 command, your `lambda:animate()` seems to miss the `i` parameter.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried almost everything. Yeah (i) doesnt return anything either. I tried moving that whole command into the button command but no luck..

Is there some way where I can move 'ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(f1,animate, interval = 1000)' in the button command so that it starts printing the graphs only when it is asked to..?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, dirty hack:

```
global do_animate
do_animate = False
```

change your command as follows:

```
#creating button
#if agree then move to temperature graph
button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Start Monitoring", 
                    command=lambda: do_animate=True)  # with lambda we are moving from start page to page 1
```

and in `animate` just return `if do_animate == False`

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Jean I tried that but it doesn't display the graphs when the 'ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(f1,animate, interval = 1000)' command is moved from there.

Comment: changed the solution

Comment: Unfortunately no output. Thanks for your effort and help Jean seems like this animation function is pain, i should try doing something simple. :D

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong with the global variable stuff. I hate global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jean-François Fabre's solution, this is not gonna stop your animate() from running, but it is gonna stop it from doing anything.

```
def animate(i):
   global draw
   if draw:
      """ here goes all you want your animate func to do """
   draw = False
```

So by adding what you wanna do inside of the if draw you will make sure it will only be drawn once and then not again. Should you want it to keep being drawn, remove the draw = False in the end. Depending on what you want, you will need to set draw in **init**.

```
class startpage(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
      global draw
      draw = False #if you want it to start without drawing
```

This is atleast how I made this kind of thing work in my program. You obviously need a way to set draw to true somewhere, and this could be whatever. In my program I set it to draw whenever I changed what to plot, but you might want a button since you want it to keep going.

Comment: Hello @Paolo
Thanks for your reply.. I am using what you said but it's showing an error in animate saying draw is not defined..
I am sorry I am a neby, I didn't undersand what 'draw=False' in 'def def __init__(self, parent, controller):' does. I think it will throw error because draw is not defined there..

Comment: sry for slow response! So the __init__ will run the first time when you start the program. So any globals declared in there will be "saved". The problem was I hadn't said it should be global there. I edited to fix it. The purpose is to let the program know that there is a variable that should be reachable from anyway and that the variable's worth is False. What this does is when your program goes into animate it will check: is Draw True? And it will know that draw is False, and not do anything within the if statement. Then you need a button to set draw to True for it to draw when you click.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way to solve my own problem. I hope it might help someone

before app.mainloop() i created a test function

```
app.geometry("1280x720")


def test():

   ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(f1,animate1, interval = 1000)
   ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(f2,animate2, interval = 1000)
   ani1._start(test)
   ani2._start(test)

app.mainloop()
```

which I passed to my command button in the page

```
button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Start Monitoring", 
                        command=lambda: test())  # with lambda we are moving from start page to page 1
```

I have no idea how is it working but it starts plotting when I ask it to..  :D

thanks again everyone.
Have a nice day